# SharePoint 2013 Access Services Config

Tags: access-services

I believe that Access Services has been properly enabled on the Sharepoint 2013 interface.

I'm especially interested in whether this might be a LICENSING issue.

But right now, I go to make a new 'Custom Web App' in Access 2013.. and I choose the name 'My New App' and the Web Location = `http://localhost`

and I get this error:

An error has occurred.

TECHNICAL DETAILS
CorrelationID: 2dc0e59b-1f2d-6095-9d86-899083c88ae5

Date and Time 11/28/2012 5:44:18 pm

I get ZERO other information other than 'OK' button.

Where can I go and research this error?

Google hasn't helped me find much :(

Answer (score 3):

The actual details of your error will be in SharePoint's ULS log files. The key here is the **correlation ID** that has been listed out. You have to parse through the appropriate log file and filter down to log events that use that correlation ID. Then, within that group of items, there should be more detailed error messages about what happened.

### Where to find ULS log files

They're in SharePoint's hive. Since you're using 2013, they will be in the **15** hive, which is located at:

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Logs`

SharePoint 2010 used the 14 hive, while SharePoint 2007 used the 12 hive.

Since the log files rollover, you'll need to find the log file that corresponds to the date and time you've noted in your error message. Just check the last modified date of the files and select the first one with a date/time just higher than your error.

Then search for that correlation ID. You'll get a hit for multiple lines. One or more of those lines will contain error data.

### A quicker way - ULSViewer.exe

It's good to know how and where to get to this data, but it's also nice to have some tools to help you out. ULSViewer is an unsupported Microsoft utility that parses these log files and makes it a lot easier to filter and sort based on criteria: severity, date/time, correlation ID, etc.

Download it from: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer

Check out the documentation file (it's in .docx format) to get a quick rundown of how to use it. Basically, you open the file (File > Open From > File), select the appropriate ULS log file as noted above, then modify the filter to use "CorrelationID" "equals" and paste in the GUID as the filter value. Then see what you get -- you should definitely get some results. If not, you've either opened the wrong log file, or in cases where you have load balanced servers in a farm scenario, another front-end server *might* have the data you need.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the help, that's helped me to get going in the right direction.

Right now, this is just a vm on my local machine, so I've been using localhost, that looks like it's the problem.. I Just don't really understand WTH I'm supposed to do.. I tried inventing a URL and putting it in my HOSTS file, and adding it to AAM, but apparently I don't know what I'm doing :)

Comment: here are three errors immediately preceding this GUID

Comment: #1 - first

11/29/2012 01:17:31.37  w3wp.exe (0x1A78)                        0x1A08 SharePoint Foundation          General                        adyrv High     Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri http://localhost/_vti_bin/accsvc/ServerDesignService.asmx. b8b0e59b-1fa9-6095-9d86-856f784beaab

Comment: #2 - second 11/29/2012 01:17:31.37  w3wp.exe (0x1A78)                        0x1A08 SharePoint Foundation          Configuration                  8059 Warning  Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  Users or services are accessing the site http://win-ufh2vl8en45 with the URL http://localhost.  This may cause incorrect links to be stored or returned to users.  If this is expected, add the URL http://localhost as an AAM response URL.  For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=114854"/> b8b0e59b-1fa9-6095-9d86-856f784beaab

Comment: #3 - this is where I'm getting the CorrelationID

11/29/2012 01:17:31.37  w3wp.exe (0x1A78)                        0x1A08 SharePoint Foundation          Logging Correlation Data       xmnv Medium   Name=Request (POST:http://localhost:80/_vti_bin/accsvc/ServerDesignService.asmx:CreateApplication) 1cdae59b-0f17-6095-9d86-812168881957

Comment: Your second log entry indicates you might try accessing your site via your machine name (`win-ufh2vl8en45`) rather than `localhost`. I'm not sure that'll work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: 12/03/2012 15:44:28.14  w3wp.exe (0x2160)                        0x28C8 SharePoint Foundation          Monitoring                     b4ly High     Leaving Monitored Scope (CreateApplication). Execution Time=234.877058397087 4e55e79b-2f5f-6095-9d86-8455bcf6a0e1