# Access Services - Sorry, something went wrong with adding the app

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, access-services

I am looking for any updates or further help with Access Services on SharePoint 2013.  I have reviewed [Access Services - can't get it working and I've installed everything FIVE TIMES](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59768/access-services-cant-get-it-working-and-ive-installed-everything-five-times).  The access services app is running.  App pools are running. I have checked database permissions. Everything seems to be fine. But when I try to actually use the Access App to a sharepoint site, all it does is tell me "Sorry, something went wrong."

I continually see "Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri xxx/AccessService.svc." in the logs, though that link pulls up the service.  I also still get "Access Serivces Host Layer ajiqc Medium The current application is null."

I have tried this on two environments with the same result.  I have built out the app catalog.  Verbose logging has not given me any additional information.

Does anyone out there have anything new to try or a real resolution??

Unfortunately, this system will not allow me to include log portions, because it is recognizing it as posting links.

Comment: can you browse the accessservice.svc? go to the server where Acess services running, open IIS and right click on the Access Service and browse it Under the shareaPoint web service.

Comment: also make sure the account running the access service have permission on the Configuration Database, make them DBO.

Comment: @sarwar- yes, already has dbo on the config database.   Yes I can browse to the service. Still nothing.