# System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, spweb

This error happens on every page of the site.

1. I click on link to open page like http://myportal.com/Lists/List1/
2. SharePoint open it and in url add smth like AllItems.aspx, so it url looks like http://myportal.com/Lists/List1/AllItems.aspx
3. After passing some time (3-4 minutes) I refresh this page and this error appears.

This error appears also if I stay for 3-5 minutes on one page and then click on link like http://myportal.com/SitePages/Page1.aspx to go to another.

I have done almost everything that I could find in the net:

- change the value of MaxHttpCollectionKeys
- restart services of Timer,Asp.Net state,User Profile,Search
- start sharepoint configuration wizard.

in monitoring in CA I have error only for indexing schedule manager.

I don't think that it depends on my code, because it happens everywhere on my portal. May be some SPWeb or SPSite object automatically disposing every 3-5 minutes, may be there are some utilities to check this.

Please, help me, I'm trying to decide this problem during 2 weeks, and no results..

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>   Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>
> Source Error: 
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.`
>
> Stack Trace: 
>   [InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.EnsureSPWebRequest(SPWeb web) +218
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext context) +520
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.GetContextWeb(HttpContext context) +27
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PostResolveRequestCacheHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea) +918
>      System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171`

Thanks!

UPD: 
From log:

> `08/02/2013 09:33:55.35    w3wp.exe (0x1588)                           0x1BE0  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://page.aspx) cccee8b6-0eac-4a4b-ae68-cce0c71a2646`
>
> `08/02/2013 09:33:55.36    w3wp.exe (0x1588)                           0x1BE0  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.EnsureSPWebRequest(SPWeb web)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext context)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.GetContextWeb(HttpContext context)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PostResolveRequestCacheHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)  cccee8b6-0eac-4a4b-ae68-cce0c71a2646`
>
> `08/02/2013 09:33:55.38    w3wp.exe (0x1588)                           0x1BE0  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://page.aspx)). Время выполнения=26,7436  cccee8b6-0eac-4a4b-ae68-cce0c71a2646`

Comment: Do you use a custom master page?

Comment: yes, i have custom master page, but i haven't changed it for a long time. I mean I haven't got such error earlier with this custom master page

Comment: Can you get SPSite of SPWeb object using powershell without errors?

Comment: yes, SPSite and SPWeb object works right through powershell. May be it somehow depends on cache configurations? I don't know..

Comment: You can perhaps get more information on the underlying cause of the error by looking at the ULS logs.  See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/52784/14649

Comment: In Logs there's nothing else about this error (I mean strings with the same correlation id)

Comment: I faced similar issue which whenever i tried to open a list or document library i get error, except for application pages like "_layouts/settings.aspx". i struggled so much with it until i figure out that my Antivirus Firewall blocked the communications between sharepoint and it's web services, wired i know.

Answer (score 1):

Has any custom code been deployed across all pages?

Maybe using a delegate control?

It sounds like something on the page has a misconfigured SPControlMode which can be used to change a field to render its Display or Edit Template.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spcontrolmode.aspx

---

Just looking at the logs. The request coming in which is erroring is for a url pages.aspx. I would expect it to have a full url. I.e. http://sharepoint.local/page.aspx

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I don't have code, that you've described. Now I'm setting everything to right on my portal. One of possible reason - broken list. I can't delete it because one column was lookup or smth like this, but in the end I removed it, and maybe broke something by this rude action.

Comment: I have edited url from logs before posting here. It was in full format like in your example.

Comment: Ah ok I see.. darn.